# Regex to extract text with slash separated by slashes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the element definition from the xpath string using a regex.
However, some element definitions include the slash separator itself.

Sample of xpath:

> /primary[@classCode='ABC']/subject[@typeCode='123/a'][organizer/code[@codeSystem='12.35.1.1/b']]/component[@typeCode='RET']/text()

I expect the result:

1. primary[@classCode='ABC']
2. subject[@typeCode='123/a'][organizer/code[@codeSystem='12.35.1.1/b']]
3. component[@typeCode='RET']
4. text()

Trying something simple, like

> (?<=/)(.*?)(?=/)

or similar variations is not adequate.

Is there a regex expression that splites this without further processing the string?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? This is important because features vary wildly between engines, and your data shows that you need a regex that can handle recursion/balanced parentheses. Not many can.

Comment: I'm using regex engin in SAP Sqlanywhere 16, which does not support all expressions (e.g. ".*?").

Answer (score 0):

Although there are better ways to extract xpath than using regex depending on the language, but if you still *have to* use regex, then you could try this:

```
(?<=\/|^)(.*?(?:\[.*?\])*)(?=\/|$)
```

- Lookbehind `(?<=` includes `/` or starting anchor `^`
- `(.*?(?:\[.*?\])*)` is used to extract each segment in the path

  - `(?:\[.*?\])` is a non-capturing group to match anything present within `[` and `]`
  - Used quantifier `*` with above group since xpath segment can contain more than one arguments such as `subject[][]` in your example.
- Lookahead `(?=\/|$)` includes `/` or ending anchor `$`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7tbIy/1)

```
// Output:
primary[@classCode='ABC']
subject[@typeCode='123/a'][organizer/code[@codeSystem='12.35.1.1/b']]
component[@typeCode='RET']
text()
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. My other information for this topic could be seen in my comment to previous Sahil Gulati's answer

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is used case but i hope this will help you out..

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Yd8Ciu/1)

**Regex:** `\/.*?[\]\)](?=\/|$)`

> **1.** `\/.*?[\]\)]` this will match `/` then all till first occurrence of `]` or `)`
>
> **2.** `(?=\/|$)` positive look ahead for either `/` or `$`(end of string)

Comment: Thank You for your recommendation. I was planning to use it in SAP SQL Anywhere 16, but using the ".*?" isn't supported for regexp_substr function.

Comment: One solution which may work for this problem could be to invert logic (replace / out of the square brackets with # and split the text).